# Android 10 - Set FLAG_SECURE flag cannot hide screen information

Tags: android, android-10.0

```
mContext.cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try{
                    // Disable the creation of screenshots adding the FLAG_SECURE to the window
                    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                        mContext.cordova.getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
                    }
                    callbackContext.success("Success");
                }catch(Exception e){
                    callbackContext.error(e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
        return true;
```

Tried with the code above to set the app private. The above codes work well with android 9 & 8, except for android 10. Have googled but still don't get any workaround on this issue.

Comment: `FLAG_SECURE` works on Android 10. Your reference to `cordova` suggests that you are writing an Apache Cordova plugin or something. Perhaps there is a problem in the combination of your version of Apache Cordova, your plugin, and Android 10 that is causing a problem. `setFlags()` usually needs to be called very early in the creation of the activity, so perhaps for some reason your code is being called too late on Android 10.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes I am writing a cordova plugin. The function `setFlags()` is being called while the app is put in background using function below. Somehow tested some phones with android 10 are not working, but samsung note 9 with android 10 is working. `document.addEventListener("pause", this.AppOnBackground, false);`

Comment: @CommonsWare just realized the navigation bar full screen gestures available on android 10 unable to detect the app is running in background